Are there clear "application-limits" to inflatable heat shields?
The bump of Why can't you just parachute down from orbit? got me curious about if hypersonic parachutes were even a thing, but before I found out I stumbled back across LOFTID, which apparently had a successful test.  However, a cursory glance at the literature makes it seem like all the proposed applications for inflatable decelerators like LOFTID are for Mars entry (aside from something like the old Paracone), despite the tests being at Earth.
Is there some really clear trade-off/trade-stufy that makes inflatable decelerators not attractive for reentry from LEO versus other options?  Something else like TRL too low?  Am I just wrong?
I saw Does an inflatable heat shield have some capacity to be used for LEO Earth's atmospheric entry? and GremlinWranger's answer makes some relevant claims but I'm imagining there's some clearer existing consensus about what re-entry scenarios inflatable heat shields are useful for (maybe parameterized by payload weight vs energy?).

My unsourced speculation from looking around doing the answer linked is that max Q may be a limit in terms of keeping an inflatable shield correctly shaped.

While looking into LOFTID more I found out it had an ejectable data recorder, which was tested for dropworthiness by throwing it out of an airplane. Small world; I also tested an ejectable data recorder for a NASA project by throwing it out of an airplane, but mine was for Orion Ascent Abort 2. (The data recorder was not mine, I just helped a bit, including by throwing it out of an airplane)

does TRL = Technology Readiness Level and "TRL too low" = not ready? That would certainly make a technology not attractive :-)

@uhoh thank you for the link, you made it much easier to edit the clarification in while I was eating lunch

@uhoh I did mean "trade" btw, in the sense of trade-off

ah, I see, got it.

Are you asking about tech limitations (like the title seems to suggest), or asking why they're not used for earth return today (which is often a question about markets rather than technology).

@BowlOfRed I don't want to limit the answer to the purely technical, but I want to know if there are reasons their proposed uses are being limited to Mars (apparently to me! I could be wrong!).  There could be market reasons that they're not-sufficiently-useful for LEO applications, but "why they're not used for earth return today" isn't what I'm asking.
